# How does a for loop in Python iterate through an unsubscriptable object?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, ironpython

How can the for loop in Python iterate through objects that I cannot address using the [n] notation?

Consider this:

```
myCollection # Some objects with elements (not a simple list)
for elem in myCollection:
    print elem.Title
myCollection[0]
```

The code above would in my case succeed in the for loop and will print the title string of all the elements, while the call to myCollection[0] would fail with the following exception:

```
TypeError: 'myCollection' object is unsubscriptable
```

**How does the for statement iterate through the objects?**

Is there another way to access the first element of the collection when the subscript notation fails?

#### Background

This comes up in IronPython scripting in the Spotfire application which is why I cannot give a MWE.

Here is a dir(myCollection):

```
['Equals', 'GetHashCode', 'GetType', 'Item', 'MemberwiseClone', 'Overloads',   'ReferenceEquals', 'ToString', '__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__delete__', '__doc__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__str__']
```

to illustrate the methods defined on this object. It does not have a next or **next** method and for loops still work here.

Comment: *Is there another way to access the first element of the collection when the subscript notation fails?* - Try `next(iter(myCollection))`

Comment: This does not work as it complains that "next is not defined"

Comment: However it works to write:
iterator = iter(myCollection) followed by iterator.next()

Answer (score 0):

The forloop works by calling the private__next__() method,  which returns a value.

Comment: That does not seems to be correct (at least not in my example of using IronPython). There is no method __next__ of myCollection. I have edited my question to reflect this

Comment: That is why you are getting this error.

Comment: No, since the for loop works and there is no next method the for loop cannot be using the next method. The errors only occur for myCollection[0] type access.